# How to refresh ol3 map with map.render()?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to refresh my map each time that I remove a feature without success.
I've read that with map.render() and with map.renderSync() methods you can do it but I haven't achieved to find any example.

Could anybody tell me how to use them to refresh only the map and no the entire page? Or if there is another way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The map should automatically re-render when a feature is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this great workaround at http://www.codeitive.com/0SmVVPVVPj/ol3-force-redraw-layer.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        map.once("postcompose", function(){
            //start refreshing each 3 seconds
            window.setInterval(function(){
                /// call your function here
                var params = yourLayer.getSource().getParams();
                params.t = new Date().getMilliseconds()
                yourLayer.getSource().updateParams(params); 
            }, 3000);
          }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm also trying by map.render() and map.renderSync() but its doesn't work an expect. here i'm give you tip which work like refresh map.

in below code i'm slightly moving map's view center. which is visually not affect on Clint side.

```
   //After performing your desire action like change VectorLayer style... use below code for refresh map.
    var mapCenter = map.getView().getCenter(); //Get map's view center
    var newCenter = [mapCenter[0] - 0.001, mapCenter[1] - 0.001]; //move slightly 
    map.getView().setCenter(newCenter);//Set map's view center
```